# Unity Drag and Drop Draggable item behind other UI elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I implemented drag and drop UI inventory system using the new EventSystem. It worked fine and i had no issues. But now, i needed to change one part of the inventory into a scrollable list. Dragging items into Scrollrect works fine no issues. But when i try to drag out, then i can only see the item within the scroll rect but not outside(drag and drop still works).

So i tryed to set the draggable objects parent to the canvas, but then dropping the item didnt work anymore.

How can i drag items out from scroll rect so that the draggabe object will be always on top?

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with drag and drop yet so I apologize if I am way off.
My guess is that you might have a Mask component on the Scroll Rect. 

 To fix it, you could try having an invisible object(called Master Object) that is what you actually drag. As you begin to drag a ui element, the Master Object  updates to have the image of what you are dragging. Then when dropping into place just have a script check what object or data the Master Object is currently dragging.
This would result in the Master Object never being behind anything.

 I hope this helps.
Again I apologize if this is way off.

Comment: thank you, your answer give me a clue about the problem